# scp file on iCloud Drive/Desktop to remote - OSX

Tags: scp, macos, icloud

I generally use the scp command to copy files between local and remote locations. I saved my current file on my Desktop but it seems to be stored in `/iCloud \Drive/Desktop/file` . When I try to scp this to remote using the command `scp /iCloud \Drive/Desktop/file ssh myremotelocation` it gives me an error - file not found. Using `~/Desktop/file` gives same error.

**Exact commands I tried**

```
1. scp /iCloud\ Drive/Desktop/myfile ssh alias@myremotelocation:/path/to/location
2. scp /"iCloud Drive"/Desktop/myfile ssh alias@myremotelocation:/path/to/location
3. scp ~/Desktop/myfile ssh alias@myremotelocation:/path/to/location
```

**Zsh Errors:**

```
1,2,3: iCloud Directory/Desktop/myfile : No such file of directory
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the exact scp command that you're running and the exact output that it produces. Don't paraphrase it.

Comment: What about double quotes around path (without escaping)?

Comment: I just did it. Does this help?